# Error Propagation of parameter in an irreversible equation

Tags: partial-derivative, error-propagation

I have the following equation that predicts a certain parameter $c_t$:
$$c_t = f(x,y_1,y_2,y_3...)$$
The function $f$ is known, continuous, real, differentiable to all arguments and the solution to a linear set of differential equations. I want to know $x$, and to do so I measure $c_t$ with known parameters $y_i$ and their respective uncertainties $σ_{c_t}$, $σ_{y_i}$.

If the uncertainty of $x$ was not an issue, I could simply fit $x$ so that $f(..)$ is equal to $c_t$.
Then I would use the partial derivative approach to find $σ_{x}$, but to my knowledge that is not applicable since I cannot rewrite the equation to return $x$ as in $x = g(c_t,y_1,y_2,y_3...)$

How can I calculate the expected value and uncertainty of $x$ in this case?

Comment: The meaning of "irreversible" in this context needs a little clarification.  Perhaps you mean that, due to complex nature of function $f:\mathbb{R}^{m+1}\to \mathbb{R}$, it is impractical to solve the equation for $x$.  Perhaps you mean that, after fixing the parameters $y_1,\ldots,y_m$, the resulting function $f(x)$ is not (or may not be) invertible (at least in the neighborhood of $x$ where $f(x) = c_t$.

Comment: I've assumed that $f$ is a real-valued function of real parameters/arguments.  You should probably added context, such as whether $f$ is continuous or differentiable with respect to some or all of its arguments.  In broad terms you seem to be asking about *sensitivity analysis*.

Comment: You are right, excuse me, I'm not too familiar with this field. I meant that it is not possible to rewrite the equation to return $x$ as a function of the other parameters, as in: $x = g(c_t,y_1,y_2,y_3..)$. Does that make sense?
$f$ is real, continuous and differentiable to all arguments.
It might be worth noticing that $f$ is the solution to a linear system of differential equations

Comment: It is not so much a question of "estimating $f(x,..)$ by a reversible function" as one of computing or accurately estimating the partial derivatives of $f$ with respect to each of its arguments.  From the perspective of a Reader of your Question, the function $f$ is a "black box" about which nothing is known.  However you at least have the ability to do "experiments" that (subject to measurement errors) give you the value of $f(x,y_1,\ldots,y_m)$.  There's only a limited amount of information here for me to base an Answer on.

Comment: Thank you, I will edit the question accordingly

Comment: I just thought that it might be possible to approximate $f$ using Taylor series:$$c_t(x) = f(\bar{x},y_1...) + \frac{\partial f(\bar{x},y_1...)}{\partial x} (x - \bar{x})$$
That way $x$ can be written as function of the other variables and the partial derivative approach can be applied

Answer (score 1):

Although I realize that this is not a general solution to this problem, it was possible to approximate $c_t$ as function of $x$ using a first order Taylor expansion in this scenario:

$c_t(x) = f(\bar{x},y_1...) + \frac{\partial f(\bar{x},y_1...)}{\partial x} (x - \bar{x})$

This can be written to return $x$:

$x = (c_t(x) - f(\bar{x},y_1...))/\frac{\partial f(\bar{x},y_1...)}{\partial x}+ \bar{x}$

The uncertainty in $x$ follows directly from applying the partial derivative approach to $x$